# How to connect @ManyToMany relationships in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am creating an application that uses a many to many relationship between employees and shifts. However, I am having difficulties in understanding how I can assign/connect an employee to a shift.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Employee {

private @Id @GeneratedValue long employeeID;
private String Name;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Shift> shifts;

private Employee() {
}

public Employee(long employeeID, String Name) {
    this.employeeID = employeeID;
    this.Name = Name;
}

public Employee(long employeeID, String Name, Set<Shift> shifts) {
    this.employeeID = employeeID;
    this.Name = Name;
    this.shifts = shifts;
}

public void setShift(Set<Shift> shifts) {
    this.shifts = (Set<Shift>) shifts;
}
```

}

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Shift {

private @Id @GeneratedValue long Id;
private String shifts;

private Set<Employee> employee;

private Shift() {
}

public Shift(String shifts) {
    this.shifts = shifts;
}

public Shift(String shiftPeriod,Set<Employee> employee ) {
    this.shifts = shifts;
    this.employee=employee;
}

public void setEmployee(Set<Employee> employee) {
    this.employee = employee;
}
```

}

```
@Component
public class DatabaseLoader implements CommandLineRunner {

private final EmployeeRepository repository;

@Autowired
public DatabaseLoader(EmployeeRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}

@Override
public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
    Shift shift = new Shift("Friday Morning");
    Employee employee = new Employee(0001, "Adam Smith");

    employee.setShift(shift);
    this.repository.save(employee);
}
```

}

```
public interface ShiftRepository extends CrudRepository<Shift, Long> 

public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long>
```

Entities added into employees and shifts are saved but is there a way I can assign a shift to an employee in the DatabaseLoader class, as I've been stuck on finding a solution to this.

I know that I haven't included a method which attempts to connect employee and shifts but I don't how to approach this problem.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT: The new problem I have now is that I get the following message when trying to deploy in spring:

Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: shift, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(employee)]

Comment: In JPA I always break down my Many-to-Many into a one-to-many and a many-to-one, it gives you more control over cascade and it is easier to move relations when the mapping table is explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion:

1. A shift is an independent entity. It does not depend on any employees.
   So `Shift` must not have a reference to `Employee`.
2. On the other hand an employee depend on several shifts, so `Employee` must have [unidirectional @OneToMany association](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-unidirectional) with `Shift`.

```java
    @OneToMany
    private List<Shift> shifts;
```

3. And **don't use cascading** here because `Employee` and `Shift` are independent entities.

**UPDATE**

To "add a shift to an employee" we can use for example an `Employee` setter:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    //...
    private String name;
    //...
    @OneToMany
    private List<Shift> shifts;
    //...
    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    //...
    public setShifts(Shift... shifts) {
        this.shifts = Arrays.asList(shifts);
    }
    //...
}
```

then

```
Shift monday = shiftRepository.save(new Shift("Monday"));
Shift friday = shiftRepository.save(new Shift("Friday"));
Employee adamSmith = new Employee("Adam Smith");
adamSmith.setShifts(monday, friday);
employeeRepository.save(adamSmith);
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it's really helpful! However, I'm still unsure about how I can add a shift to an employee within my DatabaseLoader class...E.g: How can I add Friday Morning to Adam Smith

Comment: 'How can I add Friday Morning to Adam Smith?' - for example with `Employee` setter - see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using Hibernate under the hood, then all you have to do is to set the objects you want to save properly, like this:

```
@Component
public class DatabaseLoader implements CommandLineRunner {

private final EmployeeRepository repository;
private final ShiftRepository shiftRepository;

@Autowired
public DatabaseLoader(EmployeeRepository repository, ShiftRepository shiftRepository) {
    this.repository = repository;
    this.shiftRepository=shiftRepository;
}

@Override
public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
    Shift shift = new Shift("Friday Morning");
    Employee employee = new Employee(0001, "Adam Smith");

    employee.setShift(shift)
    this.repository.save(employee);
}
```

The only difference is that I attached between the two objects and only then I try to save them. It's worth to mention that it's important to use Cascade.All or Cascade.persiste in order that hibernate will do the inserts on both entities.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply! However, when I try to implement your method, I get the following error: Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: shift, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(employee)]    ------------------ I've also updated my classes above so you can see exactly what changes I've made